# Move spam to Spam Folder with maildrop

Tags: email, exim, spamassassin

I have setup an exim installation with maildrop and created the `/etc/maildroprc`. Exim delivers to the Maildir folder.

**/etc/maildroprc:**

```
DEFAULT="$HOME/Maildir"
if (/^X-Spam-Flag: *YES/)
{
    to $DEFAULT/Spam/
}
```

Mail gets delivered properly (even mails marked as SPAM in subject and in headers) but always ends up in Inbox. For some reason maildrop does not move it. I know that maildrop is working as I see in exim logs:

`user <user@domain> R=maildrop T=maildrop_pipe`

And the X-Spam-Flag is set. Can see it in the mail headers and in exim.conf have:

```
warn spam = nobody:true
    add_header = X-Spam-Score: $spam_score ($spam_bar)
    add_header = X-Spam-Report: $spam_report

  # add second subject line with *SPAM* marker when message
  # is over threshold
  warn  spam = nobody
    add_header = X-Spam-Flag: YES
    add_header = Subject: ***SPAM (score:$spam_score)*** $h_Subject:
```

**My exim4.conf.template:**

```
exim_path = /usr/sbin/exim4

.ifndef CONFDIR
CONFDIR = /etc/exim4
.endif

UPEX4CmacrosUPEX4C = 1

domainlist local_domains = MAIN_LOCAL_DOMAINS

domainlist relay_to_domains = MAIN_RELAY_TO_DOMAINS

hostlist relay_from_hosts = MAIN_RELAY_NETS

.ifndef MAIN_PRIMARY_HOSTNAME_AS_QUALIFY_DOMAIN
.ifndef MAIN_QUALIFY_DOMAIN
qualify_domain = ETC_MAILNAME
.else
qualify_domain = MAIN_QUALIFY_DOMAIN
.endif
.endif

.ifdef MAIN_LOCAL_INTERFACES
local_interfaces = MAIN_LOCAL_INTERFACES
.endif

.ifndef LOCAL_DELIVERY
LOCAL_DELIVERY=mail_spool
.endif

gecos_pattern = ^([^,:]*)
gecos_name = $1

.ifndef CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_LOCALPARTS
CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_LOCALPARTS = ^[.] : ^.*[@%!/|`#&?]
.endif

.ifndef CHECK_RCPT_REMOTE_LOCALPARTS
CHECK_RCPT_REMOTE_LOCALPARTS = ^[./|] : ^.*[@%!`#&?] : ^.*/\\.\\./
.endif


.ifndef MAIN_LOG_SELECTOR
MAIN_LOG_SELECTOR = +smtp_protocol_error +smtp_syntax_error +tls_certificate_verified +tls_peerdn
.endif


.ifndef MAIN_ACL_CHECK_MAIL
MAIN_ACL_CHECK_MAIL = acl_check_mail
.endif
acl_smtp_mail = MAIN_ACL_CHECK_MAIL


.ifndef MAIN_ACL_CHECK_RCPT
MAIN_ACL_CHECK_RCPT = acl_check_rcpt
.endif
acl_smtp_rcpt = MAIN_ACL_CHECK_RCPT


.ifndef MAIN_ACL_CHECK_DATA
MAIN_ACL_CHECK_DATA = acl_check_data
.endif
acl_smtp_data = MAIN_ACL_CHECK_DATA


.ifdef MESSAGE_SIZE_LIMIT
message_size_limit = MESSAGE_SIZE_LIMIT
.endif


av_scanner = clamd:/var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl


spamd_address = 127.0.0.1 783

.ifdef MAIN_ALLOW_DOMAIN_LITERALS
allow_domain_literals
.endif


.ifndef DC_minimaldns
.ifndef MAIN_HOST_LOOKUP
MAIN_HOST_LOOKUP = *
.endif
host_lookup = MAIN_HOST_LOOKUP
.endif


.ifdef MAIN_HARDCODE_PRIMARY_HOSTNAME
primary_hostname = MAIN_HARDCODE_PRIMARY_HOSTNAME
.endif

rfc1413_query_timeout = 2s


prdr_enable = true

.ifdef MAIN_SMTP_ACCEPT_MAX_NOMAIL_HOSTS
smtp_accept_max_nonmail_hosts = MAIN_SMTP_ACCEPT_MAX_NOMAIL_HOSTS
.endif

.ifndef MAIN_FORCE_SENDER
local_from_check = false
local_sender_retain = true
untrusted_set_sender = *
.endif

.ifndef MAIN_IGNORE_BOUNCE_ERRORS_AFTER
MAIN_IGNORE_BOUNCE_ERRORS_AFTER = 2d
.endif
ignore_bounce_errors_after = MAIN_IGNORE_BOUNCE_ERRORS_AFTER

.ifndef MAIN_TIMEOUT_FROZEN_AFTER
MAIN_TIMEOUT_FROZEN_AFTER = 7d
.endif
timeout_frozen_after = MAIN_TIMEOUT_FROZEN_AFTER

.ifndef MAIN_FREEZE_TELL
MAIN_FREEZE_TELL = postmaster
.endif
freeze_tell = MAIN_FREEZE_TELL


.ifndef SPOOLDIR
SPOOLDIR = /var/spool/exim4
.endif
spool_directory = SPOOLDIR


.ifndef MAIN_TRUSTED_USERS
MAIN_TRUSTED_USERS = uucp
.endif
trusted_users = MAIN_TRUSTED_USERS
.ifdef MAIN_TRUSTED_GROUPS
trusted_groups = MAIN_TRUSTED_GROUPS
.endif


smtp_banner = $smtp_active_hostname ESMTP Exim $version_number $tod_full

.ifdef MAIN_KEEP_ENVIRONMENT
keep_environment = MAIN_KEEP_ENVIRONMENT
.else
# set option to empty value to avoid warning.
keep_environment =
.endif
.ifdef MAIN_ADD_ENVIRONMENT
add_environment = MAIN_ADD_ENVIRONMENT
.endif

tls_on_connect_ports=465
MAIN_TLS_ENABLE = yes
.ifdef MAIN_TLS_ENABLE
.ifndef MAIN_TLS_ADVERTISE_HOSTS
MAIN_TLS_ADVERTISE_HOSTS = *
.endif
tls_advertise_hosts = MAIN_TLS_ADVERTISE_HOSTS

.ifdef MAIN_TLS_CERTKEY
tls_certificate = MAIN_TLS_CERTKEY
.else
.ifndef MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE
MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE = CONFDIR/exim.crt
.endif
tls_certificate = MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE

.ifndef MAIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY
MAIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY = CONFDIR/exim.key
.endif
tls_privatekey = MAIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY
.endif

.ifndef MAIN_TLS_VERIFY_CERTIFICATES
MAIN_TLS_VERIFY_CERTIFICATES = ${if exists{/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt}\
                                    {/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt}\
                    {/dev/null}}
.endif
tls_verify_certificates = MAIN_TLS_VERIFY_CERTIFICATES

.ifdef MAIN_TLS_VERIFY_HOSTS
tls_verify_hosts = MAIN_TLS_VERIFY_HOSTS
.endif

.ifdef MAIN_TLS_TRY_VERIFY_HOSTS
tls_try_verify_hosts = MAIN_TLS_TRY_VERIFY_HOSTS
.endif

.ifdef _HAVE_GNUTLS
tls_dhparam = historic
.endif

.else
tls_advertise_hosts =
.endif

.ifdef MAIN_LOG_SELECTOR
log_selector = MAIN_LOG_SELECTOR
.endif

begin acl


acl_local_deny_exceptions:
  accept
    hosts = ${if exists{CONFDIR/host_local_deny_exceptions}\
                 {CONFDIR/host_local_deny_exceptions}\
                 {}}
  accept
    senders = ${if exists{CONFDIR/sender_local_deny_exceptions}\
                   {CONFDIR/sender_local_deny_exceptions}\
                   {}}
  accept
    hosts = ${if exists{CONFDIR/local_host_whitelist}\
                 {CONFDIR/local_host_whitelist}\
                 {}}
  accept
    senders = ${if exists{CONFDIR/local_sender_whitelist}\
                   {CONFDIR/local_sender_whitelist}\
                   {}}

  .ifdef LOCAL_DENY_EXCEPTIONS_LOCAL_ACL_FILE
  .include LOCAL_DENY_EXCEPTIONS_LOCAL_ACL_FILE
  .endif

  .ifdef WHITELIST_LOCAL_DENY_LOCAL_ACL_FILE
  .include WHITELIST_LOCAL_DENY_LOCAL_ACL_FILE
  .endif
acl_check_mail:

  accept

acl_check_rcpt:

  accept
    hosts = :
    control = dkim_disable_verify

.ifdef DC_minimaldns
  warn
    control = dkim_disable_verify
.else
.ifdef DISABLE_DKIM_VERIFY
  warn
    control = dkim_disable_verify
.endif
.endif

  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_LOCALPARTS
  deny
    domains = +local_domains
    local_parts = CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_LOCALPARTS
    message = restricted characters in address
  .endif

  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_REMOTE_LOCALPARTS
  deny
    domains = !+local_domains
    local_parts = CHECK_RCPT_REMOTE_LOCALPARTS
    message = restricted characters in address
  .endif

  accept
    .ifndef CHECK_RCPT_POSTMASTER
    local_parts = postmaster
    .else
    local_parts = CHECK_RCPT_POSTMASTER
    .endif
    domains = +local_domains : +relay_to_domains

  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_VERIFY_SENDER
  deny
    message = Sender verification failed
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    !verify = sender
  .endif

  deny
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    senders = ${if exists{CONFDIR/local_sender_callout}\
                         {CONFDIR/local_sender_callout}\
                   {}}
    !verify = sender/callout

  accept
    hosts = +relay_from_hosts
    control = submission/sender_retain
    control = dkim_disable_verify

  accept
    authenticated = *
    control = submission/sender_retain
    control = dkim_disable_verify


  require message   = nice hosts say HELO first
          condition = ${if def:sender_helo_name}

  require
    message = relay not permitted
    domains = +local_domains : +relay_to_domains

  require
    verify = recipient

  deny
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    recipients = ${if exists{CONFDIR/local_rcpt_callout}\
                            {CONFDIR/local_rcpt_callout}\
                      {}}
    !verify = recipient/callout

  deny
    message = sender envelope address $sender_address is locally blacklisted here. If you think this is wrong, get in touch with postmaster
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    senders = ${if exists{CONFDIR/local_sender_blacklist}\
                   {CONFDIR/local_sender_blacklist}\
                   {}}

  deny
    message = sender IP address $sender_host_address is locally blacklisted here. If you think this is wrong, get in touch with postmaster
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    hosts = ${if exists{CONFDIR/local_host_blacklist}\
                 {CONFDIR/local_host_blacklist}\
                 {}}

  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_REVERSE_DNS
  warn
    condition = ${if and{{def:sender_host_address}{!def:sender_host_name}}\
                      {yes}{no}}
    add_header = X-Host-Lookup-Failed: Reverse DNS lookup failed for $sender_host_address (${if eq{$host_lookup_failed}{1}{failed}{deferred}})
  .endif

  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_SPF
  deny
    message = [SPF] $sender_host_address is not allowed to send mail from \
              ${if def:sender_address_domain {$sender_address_domain}{$sender_helo_name}}.  \
              Please see \
          http://www.openspf.org/Why?scope=${if def:sender_address_domain \
              {mfrom}{helo}};identity=${if def:sender_address_domain \
              {$sender_address}{$sender_helo_name}};ip=$sender_host_address
    log_message = SPF check failed.
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    condition = ${run{/usr/bin/spfquery.mail-spf-perl --ip \
                   ${quote:$sender_host_address} --identity \
                   ${if def:sender_address_domain \
                       {--scope mfrom  --identity ${quote:$sender_address}}\
                       {--scope helo --identity ${quote:$sender_helo_name}}}}\
                   {no}{${if eq {$runrc}{1}{yes}{no}}}}

  defer
    message = Temporary DNS error while checking SPF record.  Try again later.
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    condition = ${if eq {$runrc}{5}{yes}{no}}

  warn
    condition = ${if <={$runrc}{6}{yes}{no}}
    add_header = Received-SPF: ${if eq {$runrc}{0}{pass}\
                                {${if eq {$runrc}{2}{softfail}\
                                 {${if eq {$runrc}{3}{neutral}\
                  {${if eq {$runrc}{4}{permerror}\
                   {${if eq {$runrc}{6}{none}{error}}}}}}}}}\
                } client-ip=$sender_host_address; \
                ${if def:sender_address_domain \
                   {envelope-from=${sender_address}; }{}}\
                helo=$sender_helo_name

  warn
    log_message = Unexpected error in SPF check.
    condition = ${if >{$runrc}{6}{yes}{no}}
  .endif

  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_IP_DNSBLS
  warn
    dnslists = CHECK_RCPT_IP_DNSBLS
    add_header = X-Warning: $sender_host_address is listed at $dnslist_domain ($dnslist_value: $dnslist_text)
    log_message = $sender_host_address is listed at $dnslist_domain ($dnslist_value: $dnslist_text)
  .endif

  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_DOMAIN_DNSBLS
  warn
    !senders = ${if exists{CONFDIR/local_domain_dnsbl_whitelist}\
                    {CONFDIR/local_domain_dnsbl_whitelist}\
                    {}}
    dnslists = CHECK_RCPT_DOMAIN_DNSBLS
    add_header = X-Warning: $sender_address_domain is listed at $dnslist_domain ($dnslist_value: $dnslist_text)
    log_message = $sender_address_domain is listed at $dnslist_domain ($dnslist_value: $dnslist_text)
  .endif

  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_ACL_FILE
  .include CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_ACL_FILE
  .endif

  accept
    domains = +relay_to_domains
    endpass
    verify = recipient

  accept
acl_check_data:

  .ifndef IGNORE_SMTP_LINE_LENGTH_LIMIT
  deny    message    = maximum allowed line length is 998 octets, \
                       got $max_received_linelength
          condition  = ${if > {$max_received_linelength}{998}}
  .endif

  .ifdef CHECK_DATA_VERIFY_HEADER_SYNTAX
  deny
    message = Message headers fail syntax check
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    !verify = header_syntax
  .endif

  .ifdef CHECK_DATA_VERIFY_HEADER_SENDER
  deny
    message = No verifiable sender address in message headers
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    !verify = header_sender
  .endif

  warn spam = nobody:true
    add_header = X-Spam-Score: $spam_score ($spam_bar)
    add_header = X-Spam-Report: $spam_report

  warn  spam = nobody
    add_header = X-Spam-Flag: YES
    add_header = Subject: ***SPAM (score:$spam_score)*** $h_Subject:

  .ifdef CHECK_DATA_LOCAL_ACL_FILE
  .include CHECK_DATA_LOCAL_ACL_FILE
  .endif


  accept
begin routers

.ifdef MAIN_ALLOW_DOMAIN_LITERALS
domain_literal:
  debug_print = "R: domain_literal for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = ipliteral
  domains = ! +local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
.endif
hubbed_hosts:
  debug_print = "R: hubbed_hosts for $domain"
  driver = manualroute
  domains = "${if exists{CONFDIR/hubbed_hosts}\
                   {partial-lsearch;CONFDIR/hubbed_hosts}\
              fail}"
  same_domain_copy_routing = yes
  route_data = ${lookup{$domain}partial-lsearch{CONFDIR/hubbed_hosts}}
  transport = remote_smtp

.ifdef DCconfig_internet

dnslookup_relay_to_domains:
  debug_print = "R: dnslookup_relay_to_domains for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = dnslookup
  domains = ! +local_domains : +relay_to_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
  same_domain_copy_routing = yes
  no_more

dnslookup:
  debug_print = "R: dnslookup for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = dnslookup
  domains = ! +local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
  same_domain_copy_routing = yes
  # ignore private rfc1918 and APIPA addresses
  ignore_target_hosts = 0.0.0.0 : 127.0.0.0/8 : 192.168.0.0/16 :\
                        172.16.0.0/12 : 10.0.0.0/8 : 169.254.0.0/16 :\
            255.255.255.255
  no_more

.endif


.ifdef DCconfig_local
nonlocal:
  debug_print = "R: nonlocal for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = redirect
  domains = ! +local_domains
  allow_fail
  data = :fail: Mailing to remote domains not supported
  no_more

.endif

smarthost:
  debug_print = "R: smarthost for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = manualroute
  domains = ! +local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp_smarthost
  route_list = * DCsmarthost byname
  host_find_failed = ignore
  same_domain_copy_routing = yes
  no_more

.endif

COND_LOCAL_SUBMITTER = "\
               ${if match_ip{$sender_host_address}{:@[]}\
                    {1}{0}\
        }"

real_local:
  debug_print = "R: real_local for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = accept
  domains = +local_domains
  condition = COND_LOCAL_SUBMITTER
  local_part_prefix = real-
  check_local_user
  transport = LOCAL_DELIVERY

system_aliases:
  debug_print = "R: system_aliases for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = redirect
  domains = +local_domains
  allow_fail
  allow_defer
  data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/aliases}}
  .ifdef SYSTEM_ALIASES_USER
  user = SYSTEM_ALIASES_USER
  .endif
  .ifdef SYSTEM_ALIASES_GROUP
  group = SYSTEM_ALIASES_GROUP
  .endif
  .ifdef SYSTEM_ALIASES_FILE_TRANSPORT
  file_transport = SYSTEM_ALIASES_FILE_TRANSPORT
  .endif
  .ifdef SYSTEM_ALIASES_PIPE_TRANSPORT
  pipe_transport = SYSTEM_ALIASES_PIPE_TRANSPORT
  .endif
  .ifdef SYSTEM_ALIASES_DIRECTORY_TRANSPORT
  directory_transport = SYSTEM_ALIASES_DIRECTORY_TRANSPORT
  .endif

hub_user:
  debug_print = "R: hub_user for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = redirect
  domains = +local_domains
  data = ${local_part}@DCreadhost
  check_local_user

hub_user_smarthost:
  debug_print = "R: hub_user_smarthost for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = manualroute
  domains = DCreadhost
  transport = remote_smtp_smarthost
  route_list = * DCsmarthost byname
  host_find_failed = ignore
  same_domain_copy_routing = yes
  check_local_user
.endif

userforward:
  debug_print = "R: userforward for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = redirect
  domains = +local_domains
  check_local_user
  file = $home/.forward
  require_files = $local_part:$home/.forward
  no_verify
  no_expn
  check_ancestor
  allow_filter
  forbid_smtp_code = true
  directory_transport = address_directory
  file_transport = address_file
  pipe_transport = address_pipe
  reply_transport = address_reply
  skip_syntax_errors
  syntax_errors_to = real-$local_part@$domain
  syntax_errors_text = \
    This is an automatically generated message. An error has\n\
    been found in your .forward file. Details of the error are\n\
    reported below. While this error persists, you will receive\n\
    a copy of this message for every message that is addressed\n\
    to you. If your .forward file is a filter file, or if it is\n\
    a non-filter file containing no valid forwarding addresses,\n\
    a copy of each incoming message will be put in your normal\n\
    mailbox. If a non-filter file contains at least one valid\n\
    forwarding address, forwarding to the valid addresses will\n\
    happen, and those will be the only deliveries that occur.

procmail:
  debug_print = "R: procmail for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = accept
  domains = +local_domains
  check_local_user
  transport = procmail_pipe
  # emulate OR with "if exists"-expansion
  require_files = ${local_part}:\
                  ${if exists{/etc/procmailrc}\
                    {/etc/procmailrc}{${home}/.procmailrc}}:\
                  +/usr/bin/procmail
  no_verify
  no_expn

maildrop:
  debug_print = "R: maildrop for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = accept
  domains = +local_domains
  check_local_user
  transport = maildrop_pipe
  require_files = ${local_part}:/etc/maildroprc:+/usr/bin/maildrop
  no_verify
  no_expn

.ifndef FIRST_USER_ACCOUNT_UID
FIRST_USER_ACCOUNT_UID = 0
.endif

.ifndef DEFAULT_SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_ALIAS
DEFAULT_SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_ALIAS = :fail: no mail to system accounts
.endif

COND_SYSTEM_USER_AND_REMOTE_SUBMITTER = "\
               ${if and{{! match_ip{$sender_host_address}{:@[]}}\
                        {<{$local_user_uid}{FIRST_USER_ACCOUNT_UID}}}\
                    {1}{0}\
        }"

lowuid_aliases:
  debug_print = "R: lowuid_aliases for $local_part@$domain (UID $local_user_uid)"
  check_local_user
  driver = redirect
  allow_fail
  domains = +local_domains
  condition = COND_SYSTEM_USER_AND_REMOTE_SUBMITTER
  data = ${if exists{CONFDIR/lowuid-aliases}\
              {${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{CONFDIR/lowuid-aliases}\
              {$value}{DEFAULT_SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_ALIAS}}}\
              {DEFAULT_SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_ALIAS}}

local_user:
  debug_print = "R: local_user for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = accept
  domains = +local_domains
  check_local_user
  local_parts = ! root
  transport = LOCAL_DELIVERY
  cannot_route_message = Unknown user

mail4root:
  debug_print = "R: mail4root for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = redirect
  domains = +local_domains
  data = /var/mail/mail
  file_transport = address_file
  local_parts = root
  user = mail
  group = mail

begin transports

.ifdef HIDE_MAILNAME
REMOTE_SMTP_HEADERS_REWRITE=*@+local_domains $1@DCreadhost frs : *@ETC_MAILNAME $1@DCreadhost frs
REMOTE_SMTP_RETURN_PATH=${if match_domain{$sender_address_domain}{+local_domains}{${sender_address_local_part}@DCreadhost}{${if match_domain{$sender_address_domain}{ETC_MAILNAME}{${sender_address_local_part}@DCreadhost}fail}}}
.endif

.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_FROM_DNS
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA
REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA==${lookup dnsdb {ptr=$sending_ip_address}{$value}{$primary_hostname}}
.else
REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA=${lookup dnsdb {ptr=$sending_ip_address}{$value}{$primary_hostname}}
.endif
.endif

address_file:
  debug_print = "T: address_file for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = appendfile
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add

address_pipe:
  debug_print = "T: address_pipe for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = pipe
  return_fail_output

address_reply:
  debug_print = "T: autoreply for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = autoreply

mail_spool:
  debug_print = "T: appendfile for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = appendfile
  file = /var/mail/$local_part
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add
  group = mail
  mode = 0660
  mode_fail_narrower = false

maildir_home:
  debug_print = "T: maildir_home for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = appendfile
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_MAILDIR_LOCATION
  directory = MAILDIR_HOME_MAILDIR_LOCATION
  .else
  directory = $home/Maildir
  .endif
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_CREATE_DIRECTORY
  create_directory
  .endif
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_CREATE_FILE
  create_file = MAILDIR_HOME_CREATE_FILE
  .endif
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add
  maildir_format
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_DIRECTORY_MODE
  directory_mode = MAILDIR_HOME_DIRECTORY_MODE
  .else
  directory_mode = 0700
  .endif
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_MODE
  mode = MAILDIR_HOME_MODE
  .else
  mode = 0600
  .endif
  mode_fail_narrower = false

maildrop_pipe:
  debug_print = "T: maildrop_pipe for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = pipe
  path = "/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"
  command = "/usr/bin/maildrop"
  message_prefix =
  message_suffix =
  return_path_add
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add

procmail_pipe:
  debug_print = "T: procmail_pipe for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = pipe
  path = "/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"
  command = "/usr/bin/procmail"
  return_path_add
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add

DKIM_CANON = relaxed
DKIM_SELECTOR = xxxxxxxxxx
DKIM_DOMAIN = <my_domain>
DKIM_FILE = /etc/exim4/<my_domain>-private.key

remote_smtp:
  debug_print = "T: remote_smtp for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = smtp
.ifndef IGNORE_SMTP_LINE_LENGTH_LIMIT
  message_size_limit = ${if > {$max_received_linelength}{998} {1}{0}}
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HOSTS_AVOID_TLS
  hosts_avoid_tls = REMOTE_SMTP_HOSTS_AVOID_TLS
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HEADERS_REWRITE
  headers_rewrite = REMOTE_SMTP_HEADERS_REWRITE
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_RETURN_PATH
  return_path = REMOTE_SMTP_RETURN_PATH
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA
  helo_data=REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA
.endif
.ifdef DKIM_DOMAIN
dkim_domain = DKIM_DOMAIN
.endif
.ifdef DKIM_SELECTOR
dkim_selector = DKIM_SELECTOR
.endif
.ifdef DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY
dkim_private_key = DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY
.endif
.ifdef DKIM_CANON
dkim_canon = DKIM_CANON
.endif
.ifdef DKIM_STRICT
dkim_strict = DKIM_STRICT
.endif
.ifdef DKIM_SIGN_HEADERS
dkim_sign_headers = DKIM_SIGN_HEADERS
.endif
.ifdef TLS_DH_MIN_BITS
tls_dh_min_bits = TLS_DH_MIN_BITS
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
tls_certificate = REMOTE_SMTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_PRIVATEKEY
tls_privatekey = REMOTE_SMTP_PRIVATEKEY
.endif

remote_smtp_smarthost:
  debug_print = "T: remote_smtp_smarthost for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = smtp
.ifndef IGNORE_SMTP_LINE_LENGTH_LIMIT
  message_size_limit = ${if > {$max_received_linelength}{998} {1}{0}}
.endif
  hosts_try_auth = <; ${if exists{CONFDIR/passwd.client} \
        {\
        ${lookup{$host}nwildlsearch{CONFDIR/passwd.client}{$host_address}}\
        }\
        {} \
      }
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_HOSTS_AVOID_TLS
  hosts_avoid_tls = REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_HOSTS_AVOID_TLS
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_HOSTS_REQUIRE_TLS
  hosts_require_tls = REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_HOSTS_REQUIRE_TLS
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HEADERS_REWRITE
  headers_rewrite = REMOTE_SMTP_HEADERS_REWRITE
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_RETURN_PATH
  return_path = REMOTE_SMTP_RETURN_PATH
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA
  helo_data=REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA
.endif
.ifdef TLS_DH_MIN_BITS
tls_dh_min_bits = TLS_DH_MIN_BITS
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_TLS_CERTIFICATE
tls_certificate = REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_TLS_CERTIFICATE
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_PRIVATEKEY
tls_privatekey = REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_PRIVATEKEY
.endif

address_directory:
  debug_print = "T: address_directory for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = appendfile
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add
  check_string = ""
  escape_string = ""
  maildir_format

begin retry

*                      *           F,2h,15m; G,16h,1h,1.5; F,4d,6h

begin rewrite

.ifndef NO_EAA_REWRITE_REWRITE
*@+local_domains "${lookup{${local_part}}lsearch{/etc/email-addresses}\
                   {$value}fail}" Ffrs
# identical rewriting rule for /etc/mailname
*@ETC_MAILNAME "${lookup{${local_part}}lsearch{/etc/email-addresses}\
                   {$value}fail}" Ffrs
.endif

begin authenticators

 plain_saslauthd_server:
   driver = plaintext
   public_name = PLAIN
   server_condition = ${if saslauthd{{$auth2}{$auth3}}{1}{0}}
   server_set_id = $auth2
   server_prompts = :
   .ifndef AUTH_SERVER_ALLOW_NOTLS_PASSWORDS
   server_advertise_condition = ${if eq{$tls_in_cipher}{}{}{*}}
   .endif

cram_md5:
  driver = cram_md5
  public_name = CRAM-MD5
  client_name = ${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$host}nwildlsearch{CONFDIR/passwd.client}{$value}fail}}}
  client_secret = ${extract{2}{:}{${lookup{$host}nwildlsearch{CONFDIR/passwd.client}{$value}fail}}}

PASSWDLINE=${sg{\
                ${lookup{$host}nwildlsearch{CONFDIR/passwd.client}{$value}fail}\
            }\
            {\\N[\\^]\\N}\
            {^^}\
        }

plain:
  driver = plaintext
  public_name = PLAIN
.ifndef AUTH_CLIENT_ALLOW_NOTLS_PASSWORDS
  client_send = "<; ${if !eq{$tls_out_cipher}{}\
                    {^${extract{1}{:}{PASSWDLINE}}\
             ^${sg{PASSWDLINE}{\\N([^:]+:)(.*)\\N}{\\$2}}\
           }fail}"
.else
  client_send = "<; ^${extract{1}{:}{PASSWDLINE}}\
            ^${sg{PASSWDLINE}{\\N([^:]+:)(.*)\\N}{\\$2}}"
.endif

login:
  driver = plaintext
  public_name = LOGIN
.ifndef AUTH_CLIENT_ALLOW_NOTLS_PASSWORDS
  client_send = "<; ${if and{\
                          {!eq{$tls_out_cipher}{}}\
                          {!eq{PASSWDLINE}{}}\
                         }\
                      {}fail}\
                 ; ${extract{1}{::}{PASSWDLINE}}\
         ; ${sg{PASSWDLINE}{\\N([^:]+:)(.*)\\N}{\\$2}}"
.else
  client_send = "<; ${if !eq{PASSWDLINE}{}\
                      {}fail}\
                 ; ${extract{1}{::}{PASSWDLINE}}\
         ; ${sg{PASSWDLINE}{\\N([^:]+:)(.*)\\N}{\\$2}}"
.endif
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you add more off your `exim.conf`? This doesn't relieve how and when Spamassassin adds the header etc.

Comment: Its a bog standard exim installation on Debian Stretch. Just uncommented the spamassassin setting and the the spam settings.

Comment: Does `$HOME/Maildir/Spam` already exist?

Comment: Yes created it manually

Comment: There's still some missing pieces of the puzzle. Could you prepare your entire `exim.conf` for posting here, with all effective lines? (Take the whole configuration file, remove comments, sanitize any domain names or similar.)